# Closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\frac{y^m}{(n+1-m)!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, closed-form, bessel-functions

For the following infinite series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\frac{y^m}{(n+1-m)!}$$

Is there any closed expression for this infinite sum in terms of $x,y$? My intuitive thought leads me to power series related to gamma function, inverse gamma function, beta function or Bessel functions. Or maybe there is none. I welcome any hint or thought.

Comment: Equivalent to $$ \sum _{m=0}^{\infty} y^m \cdot x^{\frac{m}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot  I_{1-m}\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)  $$

Comment: By re-indexing you can write it in terms of $f(x,y) = \sum_{m \leq n} \frac{x^n}{n!} \frac{y^m}{m!}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a closed form with the [**Marcum Q**](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) [**function**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MarcumQ.html) since @Claude Leibovici noted:

$$y\,e^{\frac{1}{y}}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+2,\frac{1}{y}\right)}{n! (n+1)!}(xy)^n = y\,e^{\frac{1}{y}}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{Q \left(n+2,\frac{1}{y}\right)}{n!}(xy)^n $$

and

$$e^aQ_m(\sqrt{2 a},\sqrt{2 b})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(m+n,b)}{n!\Gamma(m+n)}a^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Q(m+n,b)}{n!}a^n $$

with [gamma regularized $Q(a,z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gammaregularized). Therefore:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\frac{y^m}{(n+1-m)!}=ye^{xy+\frac1y}Q_2\left(\sqrt{2xy},\sqrt\frac2y\right)$$

which [**is true**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BKhinchin+e%5E%28Baxter+khinchin+%2B1%2Fkhinchin%29+MarcumQ%282%2Csqrt%282+Baxter+khinchin%29%2Csqrt%282%2Fkhinchin%29%29+-Sum%5BBaxter%5En%2Fn%21+Sum%5Bkhinchin%5Em%2F%28n%2B1-m%29%21%2C%7Bm%2C0%2Cn%2B1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C100%7D%5D%2C20%5D)

Comment: Always impressive ! Cheers and (+1) for sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: For `x=1` and `y=1` correct answer is: `6.42496`, but yours formula gives: `3.3597`? I tried in Mathematica :`N[y Exp[x y + 1/y]*MarcumQ[2, Sqrt[2 x y], Sqrt[2/y]] - 
    y Exp[x y + 1/y] + 
    Sqrt[y ]*Exp[1/y]*Gamma[1/y]*BesselI[1, 2*Sqrt[x y]]/Sqrt[x] /. 
   x -> 1 /. y -> 1]`

Comment: The correct formula is: `E^(1/y + x y) y MarcumQ[2, Sqrt[2 x y], Sqrt[2/y]]`

Comment: I have tested it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Beside $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}\frac{y^m}{(n+1-m)!}=y\,e^{\frac{1}{y}}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+2,\frac{1}{y}\right)}{n! (n+1)!}(xy)^n$$ I do not see what we could write.

Even $y=x$ does not lead to anything.